# Is this a strange relationship between individual and joint p-values?

Tags: p-value, synthetic-cohort

I have two outcomes with 5 weekly effects for each one that stem from a synthetic cohort analysis. The two tables below show the p-value for each week (for the null that the effect is zero in that week), along with a joint p-value (for the null that all five effects are zero).

```
Outcome 1:    
    Week    p-value for each week
        1       0.51
        2       0.22
        3       0.13
        4       0.09
        5       0.03
        Joint p-value:  0.41

 Outcome 2: 
        Week    p-value for each week
        1       0.12
        2       0.65
        3       0.12
        4       0.16
        5       0.07
        Joint p-value:  0.19
```

**I am little puzzled why the joint p-value for outcome 2 is so low, whereas it is much higher for outcome 1.** Does this seem strange? Or am I overthinking things?

To give more context, these p-values come from repeating a synthetic cohort analysis on randomly sampled untreated units to get a set of placebo results and then comparing to the results of the actual treated unit(s).

The weekly p-values are the proportions of standardized placebo effects that are at least as large as the actual effect in each week.

The joint p-value is the proportion of placebos that have a ratio of post-treatment RMSPE over pre-treatment RMSPE at least as large as the average ratio for the treated units.

All these effects are standardized by dividing the by the corresponding pre-treatment match quality.

Comment: You say the $p$-values are proportions. So just to be clear, these $p$-values aren't the typical sort of $p$-value from a statistical test?

Comment: They are non-parametric ones based on randomization inference.

Comment: Are your sample sizes all the same?

Comment: It is the same 3 treated units for each outcome, but the two outcomes could have different synthetic cohorts, so those treated units could be matched with different states. The underlying data is the same, with no missing observations and the same set of potential donors to make up the synthetic cohort.